# Split command line argument into arguments/a vector using C++

Tags: c++, command-prompt

I have a C++ project that was previously receiving multiple command line arguments with code like so:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  for (int i = 1; i < 4; i = i + 1) {
    // do some stuff with argv[i]
    int in_arg = m[argv[i]];
  }

  return 0
}
```

Using this code, an example command line argument might be:

```
C:\MyFolder\MyExecutable.exe 4 0 1
```

However, due to plugging this code into a wider project my command line will now have to look like this instead:

```
C:\MyFolder\MyExecutable.exe 401
```

How can I split the argument `401` into a vector or similar that is functionally the same as having three input arguments like `4 0 1` so that my line:

```
int in_arg = argv[i];
```

...could be repointed to something like:

```
int in_arg = new_vector[i];
```

I only dabble with C++, so apologies if I am asking basic questions.

Thanks

Comment: Each of the arguments can exceed size of char? And also the arguments can be for example 40 10 12 if so the below solution will produce 401012-> 4 0 1 0 1 2 which is 6 arguments.

Comment: @Nazim The argument `401` shows up in the program as a `char*` pointing at the first of 4 `char`s: `'4', '0', '1', '\0'` - so there's no risk of overflow. And also, if only one argument is needed, then only bother with the first argument.

Comment: In `int in_arg = m[argv[i]];` I assume you mean `int in_arg = m[*argv[i]];` - is that correct?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No. Why?

Comment: Because `argv[i]` is a `char*` and `*argv[i]` is a `char`. `m[argv[i]]` will certainly cause problems (undefined behavior) if you can get that to compile.

Comment: Ah right, hadn’t thought of that.

Comment: You could update the question to reflect your actual code. How is the lookup table `m[]` defined? Is it `int m[256]` and then it's filled with some values? If so, what happens if the user enters a letter that shows up as a negative `char` value?

Comment: @gdogg371 Did any of the answers help? The question is still listed as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know that the 1st argument is the one to use it's simple, copy it to a string and then access it using one of the iteration options given by C++, I'm using a foreach type cycle:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{    
    if(argc < 2){
        std::cout << "Not enough arguments";  //<-- args check
        return 0;
    }
    std::string s1;
    s1 = argv[1]; //<-- copy argument to a string type to use string iterator
    std::vector<int> args_vector;

    for (char c : s1) {
        args_vector.push_back(c - '0'); // convert char to integer and save it in vector
    }

    for(int i: args_vector){ // print the args in integer format, 1 by 1
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use `static_cast<int>(c - '0')` instead of `static_cast<int>(c - 48)` (actually `c - '0'` is all you really need since it is already an `int`)

Comment: I guess it's simpler that, way, I'm a big fan of simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You could create `string`s out of the arguments and just go though them character by character:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int cppmain(std::string program, std::vector<std::string> args) {
    std::cout << program << " got " << args.size() << " argument(s):\n";

    for(auto& arg : args) {              // each argument as a string
        std::cout << " " << arg << '\n';

        for(char ch : arg) {             // each char in the current argument
            if(ch < 0) continue;         // skip negative char:s

            int in_arg = m[ch];          // assuming it was: int in_arg = m[*argv[i]];

            // use in_arg

        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //
    //         string from char*
    //                |
    //                V
    return cppmain(argv[0], {argv + 1, argv + argc});
    //                      ^                     ^
    //                      |                     |
    //                     vector<string> from char*[]
}
```